# Various Python on MacBook Pro

Tags: python

People,

I'm using a MacBook Pro 2013 with Catalina 10.15.4 and have installed various Python.

I've already tried toes brew, peen, pip and all of them. I'm learning python but I don't know the best way to let python installed in my computer.

How can i resolve this and let only the newest version? What is the best way to make python install on Mac?

Comment: https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/mac-os/

Comment: I recommend you try pyenv (https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) for installing various python versions. Its easy to use, and super useful

Comment: You can use different python environment manager such as [conda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/), [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv), [pipenv](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv). I highly recommend conda if it is fully new to you. Conda is heavier for installation etc, but you will find lot of helpful resources and it is easier to use for your first steps in python world :)